# How to prove $\det (A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det A}$ without using the property that $\det (AA^{-1})=\det (A) \det(A^{-1})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inverse

Let A be an invertible matrix.
How to prove $\det (A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det A}$ without using the property that $\det (AA^{-1})=\det (A) \det(A^{-1})$?
Thanks.
I think $\det (A^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\det A}$ holds even without this property, given A is invertible.

Comment: It's hard to speculate about whether a true statement holds "without" another true statement.

Comment: If you interpret the determinate as ratio of volume, then the result is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys. I think I figured it out. All I have to prove is that for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of A, $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.
In this way, I don't need that property to prove this question.

Comment: well, you also want to show that multiplicities are the same, but it's probably easy